# isolateScope() returns undefined when using templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I have a directive that I want to unittest, but I'm running into the issue that I can't access my isolated scope. Here's the directive:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

And the code behind it:

```
angular.module('demoApp.directives').directive('myDirective', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/directives/my-directive.html',
        scope: {},
        link: function($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            $scope.save = function() {
                $log.log('Save data');
            };

        }

    };
});
```

And here's my unittest:

```
describe('Directive: myDirective', function() {
    var $compile, $scope, $log;

    beforeEach(function() {
        // Load template using a Karma preprocessor (http://tylerhenkel.com/how-to-test-directives-that-use-templateurl/)
        module('views/directives/my-directive.html');
        module('demoApp.directives');
        inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$log_) {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $log = _$log_;
            spyOn($log, 'log');
        });
    });

    it('should work', function() {
        var el = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
        console.log('Isolated scope:', el.isolateScope());
        el.isolateScope().save();
        expect($log.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But when I print out the isolated scope, it results in `undefined`. What really confuses me though, if instead of the `templateUrl` I simply use `template` in my directive, then everything works: `isolateScope()` has a completely `scope` object as its return value and everything is great. Yet, somehow, when using `templateUrl` it breaks. Is this a bug in `ng-mocks` or in the Karma preprocessor?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i guess it should be module('views/directives/my-directive.html'); not module('views/directives/my-directive'); ...

Comment: Whoops! Already had it _with_ extensions in my test, corrected it in my sample above.

Comment: Stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem. It seems that when calling `$compile(element)($scope)` in conjunction with using a `templateUrl`, the digest cycle isn't automatically started. So, you need to set it off manually:

```js
it('should work', function() {
    var el = $compile('<my-directive></my-directive>')($scope);
    $scope.$digest();    // Ensure changes are propagated
    console.log('Isolated scope:', el.isolateScope());
    el.isolateScope().save();
    expect($log.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I'm not sure why the `$compile` function doesn't do this for you, but it must be some idiosyncracy with the way that `templateUrl` works, as you don't need to make the call to `$scope.$digest()` if you use an inline template.

Comment: el.isolateScope() returns 'undefined'

Comment: Note that you have to call $digest() on the rootScope, otherwise this won't work

Answer (score 14):

With Angularjs 1.3, if you disable `debugInfoEnabled` in the app config:

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

`isolateScope()` returns `undefined` also!

Answer (score 12):

I had to mock and flush the `$httpBackend` before `isolateScope()` became defined. Note that `$scope.$digest()` made no difference.

Directive:

```
app.directive('deliverableList', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/deliverable-list-directive.tpl.html',
        controller: 'deliverableListDirectiveController',
        restrict = 'E',
        scope = {
            deliverables: '=',
            label: '@'
        }
    }
})
```

test:

```
it('should be defined', inject(function ($rootScope, $compile, $httpBackend) {
    var scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $httpBackend.expectGET('app/directives/deliverable-list-directive.tpl.html').respond();

    var $element = $compile('<deliverable-list label="test" deliverables="[{id: 123}]"></deliverable-list>')(scope);

    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

    expect($element).toBeDefined();
    expect($element.controller).toBeDefined();

    scope = $element.isolateScope();
    expect(scope).toBeDefined();
    expect(scope.label).toEqual('test');
    expect(scope.deliverables instanceof Array).toEqual(true);
    expect(scope.deliverables.length).toEqual(1);
    expect(scope.deliverables[0]).toEqual({id: 123});
}));
```

I'm using Angular 1.3.

Comment: Super useful - this solved my issue and I'm using Angular 1.3

Comment: This solution causes the directive to be compiled with a blank template

Answer (score 2):

You could configure [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) plugin. It will convert the HTML templates into a javascript string and put it into Angular's `$templateCache` service.

After set a `moduleName` in the configuration you can declare the module in your tests and then all your production templates will available without need to mock them with `$httpBackend` everywhere.

```
beforeEach(module('partials'));
```

You can find how to setup the plugin here: http://untangled.io/how-to-unit-test-a-directive-with-templateurl/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I kept running into this in cases where I was trying to isolate a scope on a directive with no isolate scope property.

```
function testDirective() {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    template:'<span>{{ message }}</span>'
    scope:{} // <-- Removing this made an obvious difference
  };
}
function testWithoutIsolateScopeDirective() {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    template:'<span>{{ message }}</span>'
  };
}
describe('tests pass', function(){
  var compiledElement, isolatedScope, $scope;
  beforeEach(module('test'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compiledElement = $compile(angular.element('<div test-directive></div>'))($scope);
    isolatedScope = compiledElement.isolateScope();
  }));
  it('element should compile', function () {
    expect(compiledElement).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('scope should isolate', function () {
    expect(isolatedScope).toBeDefined();
  });
});
describe('last test fails', function(){
  var compiledElement, isolatedScope, $scope;
  beforeEach(module('test'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope){
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compiledElement = $compile(angular.element('<div test-without-isolate-scope-directive></div>'))($scope);
    isolatedScope = compiledElement.isolateScope();
  }));
  it('element should compile', function () {
    expect(compiledElement).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('scope should isolate', function () {
    expect(isolatedScope).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```